# How to capture text value from input field, and pass it to new input field

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

I want couple of things happen simultaneously on `keypress()` event, I got two pages, default.html where there is a input text box and another page.html with another input text box, Now what I need is that the moment a key is pressed to type a letter in to the input text box on default.html, `keypress()` fires (I need this on keypress, not on keyup or keydown) and the 'letter' is captured

```
var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
```

and at same time page is redirected

```
document.location= "page.html"; return false;
```

to 'page.html' showing the 'letter' in the input text field which was typed on previous page.
  I have got incomplete code..

```
    $(document).keypress(function(){

     var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

         document.location= "page.html";

         return false;

       }

   });
```

don't know how to use var c here to show the value into the text field on next page(page.html).

javascript code on page.html...please correct and help with this code..
I picked it up from another post..I can see that the value typed on 
default.html page shows up in the address bar of page.html
but does not show in the input text box, I know for sure I 
am doing it incorrectly. The code is mentioned below.

input field on default.html  - `<input id="search" type="text" name="searchbar">`

input field on page.html - `<input id="search2" type="text" name="searchbar2">`

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var queryString = new Array();
        $(function () {
         if (queryString.length == 0) {
             if (document.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                var params = document.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                    var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                    queryString[key] = value;
               }
              }
            }
             if (queryString["name"] != null) {
             var data = "<u>Values from QueryString</u><br /><br />";
             data += "<b>Name:</b> " + queryString["name"];
             $("#search1").html(data);
         }
       });
     </script>
```

Comment: input field on default.html  -    <input id="search" type="text" name="searchbar">
input field on page.html -        <input id="search2" type="text" name="searchbar2">

Comment: I am sorry for late reply, 'search1' is on page.html I am sorry for that again it is not search2 it is rather 'search1'.

Comment: Firstly, are you passing the parameter 'name' in the querystring?

Comment: Second, to set the value of a text box use .val() not .html()

Comment: If you want to print html on the page dont use an input tag.

Comment: sir the code above that you see I have not able to understand fully

Comment: ..and therefor could not modify it fully, I also did not understand why we are passing name there as I said I picked up the code for simple purpose to extract the value or the character typed on default.html' text box and make it appear on page.html' text box, you are the expert, I am still learning  ..

Comment: I know I am pretty freakin dumb but I will appreciate a lot I anyone can help me here..

Answer (score 1):

You can send the character in the query string like this:

```
document.location = "page.html?c=" + c;
```

Then, you can read it in JavaScript on page.html with

```
document.location.search
```

Comment: Please check I have added further codes above in my post